# UIView Constraints Settings iOS Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

I want to specify leading, trailing constraints for one of my UIView object. But when I set that I was getting following kind of red warning:

[image]

Details about constraints error:

[image]

Why I was getting this kind of error that is big question in my mind!! I have tried with multiple combination of constraints too because I am aware that constraints always need in combination.

### Edit

Set all 4 constraints:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You did not set the ImageView vertically position.
Specify the upper and lower limit for UIImageView. 
Or set height for UIImageView and set central vertical position.

Comment: you need to set constraints of header view

Comment: You have Trailing & Leading: Horizontal constraint. But what about its vertical ones: height? Top Space? Bottom Space? Center Y? Ratio?

Comment: The error is about HeaderView, not Image View missing constraints. But it's true that the ImageView was missing too this kind of horizontal constraints

Comment: Don't post a new question that is the same as your other question. Just as I was explaining to you about your "FooterView", you have to constrain your "HeaderView" to ***its*** superview --- ***not*** just for the contents of your "HeaderView".

Answer (score 0):

For the constraints in iOS development, you must define constraints for both side: vertical and horizontal. Like in the picture, you've created only constraints for horizontal side. The XCode requires the vertical side (top, botom, center_vertical, height)

Comment: Does the header view have any constraints? Because the ImageView position/ size depend on HeaderView but the size/ position of HeaderView is free